# If $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x = 1,$ then $f(0) = 0$?

Tags: limits

> If $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$ then $f(0) = 0$?

How am I supposed to approach this problem?

If-Then problems are a huge weakness of mine and I am trying to improve.

What should I be pulling on to solve this problem?

My first thought is the limit laws and try to contradict it.

I feel as though $f(x)$ could equal anything. It doesn't need to be $0$ for the limit to be true.

Comment: Read your title.  Is there an error in your statement?  $\lim_{x\to 0}f(0)$ seems pointless...

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Why yes, I have fixed it.

Comment: Your feeling that $f(0)$ could be anything is correct. To back this up, try to define a function with this property for which $f(0) = 1001$.

Comment: @HansEngler You mean like f(x)=1001+x ?

Comment: @user312484 Well, do you think $f(x)/x\to 1$ would hold with that $f(x)$? Instead define your function to be $x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $1001$ if $x=0$.

Comment: @Gary Much like the solution given below. I see.

Comment: A limit statement beginning with $\lim_{x\to 0}$ specifically implies that it is about values of $x\neq 0$ so there is no way to infer anything about $f(0)$ from that statement.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f$ could be anything at zero. For instance, take
$$f=\begin{cases}x&\text{if $x\neq 0$;}\\1&\text{if $x=0$.}\end{cases}$$
Now $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)/x = 1$ and $f(0)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the definition of limit,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}x=1\Leftrightarrow\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0, \forall x, \color{red}{0<}|x-0|<\delta\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)}x-1\right|<\epsilon$$

Note $\color{red}{0<}|x-0|<\delta$, which means there is no restriction for the value of the function at $x=0$, hence you can define the function to be any value at $x=0$, or even undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: I've yet to really grasp the precise definition of a limit.

Comment: Definition is the most fundamental thing to be applied to judge this kind of if-then problems.

Answer (score 0):

$f(0)$ could be anything even without being defined. The limit is defined in a punctured neighborhood of $0$. Recall the definition:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=a \mathrm{}$$
if and only if
$$ \forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,s.t. 0<{|x|<\delta}\Rightarrow |f(x)-a|<\epsilon $$
In the definition, $x$ isn't required to be defined at $0$